# Cold Fusion 9 - Remove JSON string from text

Tags: json, regex, coldfusion-9

I am generating a preview of certain length out of a text string. The text was made out of a HTML string where the HTML code has been removed. Because of certain reasons there are some JSON block within the text. These JSON blocks are placeholders to retrieve information from a database and replace the json string with it on page load.

For the preview the JSON must not be in the string. Therefore I have to clean the string and remove the JSON blocks.

Here is an example of how the string may look:

```
Pellentesque et vulputate felis. {"bla":"blabla", "blubb":"blubablub"} Maecenas tortor ex, commodo eu massa a, vehicula cursus erat. Nam rhoncus, nunc ut lobortis pretium, libero lorem {"blurb":"blarblar", "blabb":"blabablurb", "test":"testatest"} facilisis urna, et gravida tellus turpis ut nisi. Nulla in ullamcorper metus. Sed sed blandit magna. Integer fermentum.
```

How do I get these two JSON blocks using regex and remove it?

```
{"bla":"blabla", "blubb":"blubablub"}
{"blurb":"blarblar", "blabb":"blabablurb", "test":"testatest"}
```

It works with Rematch() and a following cfloop over the array of JSON blocks. But is it possible with ReReplace()?

**Just found the solution**

```
ReReplace(mystring, "\{([^}]*)\}", "", "ALL")
```

Sry for bothering.

Comment: Simply write the solution as an answer below, instead of an edit in your question (yes, you can answer your own questions here). Note that your approach does not work for JSON with nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Just found the solution**

```
ReReplace(mystring, "\{([^}]*)\}", "", "ALL")
```

This solution doesn't work for JSON with nested objects but in my case it's enough.